# Cannot display two Chart.js on one HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to display more Chart.js graphics on a single HTML page, but it does not work. I tried several approaches, but none of them had a positive result. I will attach my code:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zxx">
@section('content')
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.js"></script>

        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/patternomaly@1.3.2/dist/patternomaly.min.js"></script>


    @php
    $dates = '';
    $rates = '';
    $graph_data = \App\Helpers\NjHelper::bettingData();
    foreach ($graph_data as $item){
    $dates .= "'".$item->date."',";
    $rates .= $item->bankers.",";
    }
    @endphp

    @php
    $datesValue = '';
    $ratesValue = '';
    $graph_data_value = \App\Helpers\NjHelper::bettingDataValueBets();
    foreach ($graph_data_value as $item){
    $datesValue .= "'".$item->date."',";
    $ratesValue .= $item->value_bet.",";
    }
    @endphp

<script>
$(function () {
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: [{!! $dates !!}],
        datasets: [{

            label: 'Bankers Profit Per Day',
            data: [{!! $rates !!}],

            borderColor: [
                'rgba(243, 156, 18, 1)',
                'rgba(243, 156, 18, 1)',
                'rgba(243, 156, 18, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 3
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        },
        legend: {
            labels: {

                fontSize: 20
            }
        }
    }
});



var ctx_2 = document.getElementById(chartValueBets).getContext('2d');
var chartValueBets = new Chart(ctx_2, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: [{!! $datesValue !!}],
        datasets: [{

            label: 'Value Bets Profit Per Day',
            data: [{!! $ratesValue !!}],

            borderColor: [
                'rgba(243, 156, 18, 1)',
                'rgba(243, 156, 18, 1)',
                'rgba(243, 156, 18, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 3
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        },
        legend: {
            labels: {

                fontSize: 20
            }
        }
    }
});
});
</script>
</head>
<div class="col-lg-12 col-xl-4">


        <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
        <canvas id="chartValueBets" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
        </div>
@endsection
</html>
```

The data that I want to be displayed comes from some SQL queries, this is the reason why I have those two @php sections before the charts.

Only the first chart appears on my HTML page, the one with the name "myChart".

Does anyone know what I could do in order to make the second one appear as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the following line:

```
var ctx_2 = document.getElementById(chartValueBets).getContext('2d');
```

You are missing quotation marks around "chartValueBets." If you add quotation marks, it should work properly.